# How to debug built in django code with breakpoint

Tags: django, visual-studio-code, breakpoints

Is there a way to set breakpounts in Django default codes like the ones at

```
django/cobtrib/auth/views.py
```

I tried

```
Import pdb
```

And then

```
breakpoint ()
```

But it simply ignores it. Print() does work.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what python version do you use

Comment: I'm using Python 3.8.1